# Signing a PowerShell script with self-signed certificates (and without makecert.exe)

Tags: powershell, digital-signature, self-signed

I'm trying to sign a `.ps1` using self-signed certificates (the use case is for scripts I write myself on my private dev station, so no need to use - or pay for -
 a real CA). However, no matter how many guides on the topic of certificates generation and digital signatures I read, I can't seem to get it working.

Here's what I have accomplished so far:

```
# Create a certificate to use as trusted root of the signing chain
$root = New-SelfSignedCertificate `
    -Subject "CN=PowerShell Trusted Authority" `
    -FriendlyName "PowerShell Trusted Authority" `
    -KeyUsageProperty Sign `
    -KeyUsage CertSign, CRLSign, DigitalSignature `
    -CertStoreLocation Cert:\LocalMachine\My\ `
    -NotAfter (Get-Date).AddYears(10)

# Create a certificate to use for signing powershell scripts
New-SelfSignedCertificate `
    -Signer $root `
    -Subject "CN=PowerShell Code Signing" `
    -KeyAlgorithm RSA `
    -KeyLength 2048 `
    -Type CodeSigningCert `
    -CertStoreLocation Cert:\LocalMachine\My\

# Move the root cert into Trusted Root CAs
 Move-Item "Cert:\LocalMachine\My\$($root.Thumbprint)" Cert:\LocalMachine\Root
```

All of the above done from an administrative powershell instance. After that is done, I can see both certificates, in the expected locations, in the management console, and the certificate path of the signing cert checks out as valid.

I then open a regular PS prompt and attempt to sign the script:

```
# Obtain a reference to the signing certificate
PS> $cert = Get-ChildItem Cert:\LocalMachine\My\ -CodeSigningCert

# Attempt at signing
PS> Set-AuthenticodeSignature .\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1 $cert


    Directory: C:\Users\tomas\Documents\WindowsPowerShell


SignerCertificate          Status                Path
-----------------          ------                ----
                           UnknownError          Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1
```

As you can see, the actual signing fails. Looking at the powershell file, I see that no signature has been appended to the script.

If I do the signing from an admin prompt, I seem to get a little further; a signature block is added to the script, and the thumbprint of the signing cert is printed in the output from `Set-AuthenticodeSignature`, but the status is still `UnknownError` and execution under the `AllSigned` policy is still not allowed.

```
# Output some info about the certificate:
PS> $cert | Format-List

Subject      : CN=PowerShell Code Signing
Issuer       : CN=PowerShell Trusted Authority
Thumbprint   : <omitted>
FriendlyName :
NotBefore    : 9/20/2017 10:48:59 PM
NotAfter     : 9/20/2018 11:08:59 PM
Extensions   : {System.Security.Cryptography.Oid, System.Security.Cryptography.Oid, 
                System.Security.Cryptography.Oid, System.Security.Cryptography.Oid}
```

I've tried a multitude of variants of `New-SelfSignedCertificate` incantations, especially to generate the certificate for code signing, but always with the same status message (`UnknownError`).

My ultimate goal here is to be able to have `Set-ExecutionPolicy AllSigned` and still run scripts that I've created myself. What am I missing in this process to make that work?

Comment: Interesting. Any more details about the error?

Comment: @Bill_Stewart: Unfortunately, no. The `$Error` variable is empty after this failure, and I don't get any other output anywhere that shows why it fails. Any troubleshooting suggestions are very welcome :)

Comment: What type is the `Status` property in that output?

Comment: @Bill_Stewart: It's a `System.Management.Automation.SignatureStatus` enum value.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart: More info! When I looked closer at the output (by piping it to `Format-List`, I got the `StatusMessage` property too, with value `"The certificate is not valid for the requested usage"` (in the admin prompt; the non-admin seems to not be able to access the certificate, so I'm abandoning that route).

Comment: So, I'm guessing I need something more in my second certificate for this to work. But what?

Comment: I don't know for sure, but I would suspect it has something to do with the `-KeyUsageProperty` and `-KeyUsage` parameters being used to generate the certificate.

Comment: An old one from Don Jones, have you tried makecert for the second certificate? From here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2008.04.powershell.aspx

Comment: @TimHaintz The point of this exercise is to try to make do without makecert.exe. MS gave us a PS cmdlet for creating certificates and all but discontinued makecert.exe - it's more important to me to get this to work with PS, than to stick by `AllSigned`, so if I can't get it to work I'll probably resign and just `Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned` and be done with it. But I _want_ this to be possible (and easy)!

Comment: No worries. Sorry, I just did a check for makecert and noticed it had been deprecated. Do the makecert parameters give any clues into what else might be needed for new-selfsignedcertificate? I'm having a look now.

Comment: Doing a test on my test environment, your second cert seems ok. I moved the second cert into the trusted root and it all worked fine and valid. Seems your root cert might have an error in it. Will post PS output in next comment.

Comment: [ca1]: PS C:\Users\administrator.TIMHAINTZ\Documents> # Obtain a reference to the signing certificate
$cert = Get-ChildItem Cert:\LocalMachine\My\ -CodeSigningCert

# Attempt at signing
Set-AuthenticodeSignature C:\dsc\config\dscca.ps1 $cert -verbose
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Set-AuthenticodeSignature" on target "C:\dsc\config\dscca.ps1".


    Directory: C:\dsc\config
 GOT THE SAME ERROR AS YOU

Comment: $cert = Get-ChildItem Cert:\LocalMachine\Root\ -CodeSigningCert

Set-AuthenticodeSignature C:\dsc\config\dscca.ps1 $cert 

    Directory: C:\dsc\config

SignerCertificate                         Status                                                  Path                                                   
-----------------                         ------                                                  ----                                                   
BB6A2C47B4AA44437DC23273C6FB05CB96B1BF2F  Valid                                                   dscca.ps1

Comment: The one that worked, I used your second cert without -Signer $root ` and put it into Cert:\LocalMachine\Root\

Comment: @TimHaintz: Thanks; that does seem to work. Now, why doesn't it work when I trust a certificate higher in the path?

Comment: @TomasLycken using an Enterprise CA root certificate as -signer $root, all works correctly. I have to head out this morning, will have another look this afternoon at the generation of the self signed root certificate. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Thinking about this, you don't need a certificate chain trust, therefore, you don't need your first certificate. You can use the second certificate and move it into your Trusted Root folder and it will work. Using the first certificate and then creating another certificate seems to fail because the 'root' is self signed and then can't sign another certificate.

SELF SIGNED CERTIFICATE method

```
# Create a certificate to use for signing powershell scripts
$selfsigncert = New-SelfSignedCertificate `
                -Subject "CN=PowerShell Code Signing" `
                -KeyAlgorithm RSA `
                -KeyLength 2048 `
                -Type CodeSigningCert `
                -CertStoreLocation Cert:\LocalMachine\My\

# Move the root cert into Trusted Root CAs
Move-Item "Cert:\LocalMachine\My\$($selfsigncert.Thumbprint)" Cert:\LocalMachine\Root

# Obtain a reference to the code signing cert in Trusted Root
$selfsignrootcert = "Cert:\LocalMachine\Root\$($selfsigncert.Thumbprint)"

# Sign script
Set-AuthenticodeSignature C:\powershell.ps1 $selfsignrootcert
```

If you have access to an Enterprise Root CA, you can use the method you have used in your question.

ENTERPRISE ROOT CA method (same method as you have in your question) - you need to know your Root CA certificate thumbprint

```
# Get Enterprise Root CA thumbprint
$rootcert = get-childitem Cert:\LocalMachine\Root\XXXXXXXXXXXX


# Generate certificate
$fromrootcert = New-SelfSignedCertificate `
                -Signer $rootcert `
                -Subject "CN=PowerShell Code Signing" `
                -KeyAlgorithm RSA `
                -KeyLength 2048 `
                -Type CodeSigningCert `
                -CertStoreLocation Cert:\LocalMachine\My\

# Sign script
Set-AuthenticodeSignature C:\powershell.ps1 $fromrootcert
```

Comment: Hi Tim - I know this is an old one, but I've just been trying to follow your instructions and I'm getting an error. `Error: "The given path's format is not supported."` I've re-created the certificate and followed your instructions again but am now stumped. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi Ross, are you using the self signed or Enterprise Root CA method? Which cmdlet are you getting the error on? Thanks, Tim.

Comment: @RossLyons not sure if you got the response as I didn't tag you. Sorry.

Comment: Sorry Tim - just been overwhelmed at work!
I'm using the self-signed method.

Comment: No worries @RossLyons . Is the cert being generated correctly and being moved from Cert:\LocalMachine\My\cert to Cert:\LocalMachine\Root successfully? Or is that the one you are getting the error on? Thanks, Tim.

Comment: "creating-a-self-signed"  https://blogs.u2u.be/u2u/post/creating-a-self-signed-code-signing-certificate-from-powershell       https://justinho.com/blog/2016/09/05/Signing-PowerShell-Scripts.html

Comment: Glad it helped. Thanks @ScottAnderson :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$cert = New-SelfSignedCertificate -CertStoreLocation Cert:\CurrentUser\My -Type CodeSigningCert -Subject "Code Signing"

Move-Item -Path $cert.PSPath -Destination "Cert:\CurrentUser\Root"

Set-AuthenticodeSignature -FilePath c:\go.ps1 -Certificate $cert
```

source
https://blogs.u2u.be/u2u/post/creating-a-self-signed-code-signing-certificate-from-powershell