# How can I renew Self Signed Code Signing Certificates for Powershell Scripts?

Tags: powershell, certificate, code-signing

with the following code I generated a new Self Signed Code Signing Certificate for Powershell Scripts in my CA (Not Enterprise PKI!) and deployed it via a GPO (within the PS Skript and the Root Code Signing Certificate):

```
# Create a certificate to use for signing powershell scripts

$selfsigncert = New-SelfSignedCertificate `
            -Subject "CN=PowerShell Code Signing" `
            -KeyAlgorithm RSA `
            -KeyLength 2048 `
            -Type CodeSigningCert `
            -CertStoreLocation Cert:\LocalMachine\My\
# Move the root cert into Trusted Root CAs

Move-Item "Cert:\LocalMachine\My\$($selfsigncert.Thumbprint)" Cert:\LocalMachine\Root

# Obtain a reference to the code signing cert in Trusted Root
$selfsignrootcert = "Cert:\LocalMachine\Root\$($selfsigncert.Thumbprint)"

Get-ChildItem cert:\LocalMachine\Root -CodeSigningCert

#Sign the PowerShell Script

Set-AuthenticodeSignature xxx.ps1 @(Get-ChildItem cert:\LocalMachine\Root -codesigning)[0] -IncludeChain "All"

# Verify if signature is valid
Get-AuthenticodeSignature .\xx.ps1 -Verbose | fl

# Edit Displayname of Certificate to uniquely identify the cert
(Get-ChildItem -Path Cert:\LocalMachine\Root\(ThumbprintNumer)).FriendlyName = "XXXX"
```

Now this works properly, my powershell scripts are getting signed and I can deploy it on my domain with GPO. The only bad thing is the expiration date. When I create the cert like the way I explained here, it is invalid after 1 year. Is it possible, that I can edit the expiration date when I create the cert or renew it manually?

I hope somebody has an answer for me :)

Greetings

TheLizadator

Comment: By the way, if someone is interested in the source of the code for creating the certificate check this links: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46331902/signing-a-powershell-script-with-self-signed-certificates-and-without-makecert , https://justinho.com/blog/2016/09/05/Signing-PowerShell-Scripts.html

Comment: Welcome to SO.  You can use the `-NotAfter` parameter to specify the date/time when the cert expires.  If not specified, the default is 1 year.  Technically, these certs don't contain any CA enrollment template info, so you really can't submit an actual renewal request.  You can, however, recreate (with `-CloneCert` param) a new self-signed test cert each period, then ensure it (public key only) gets deployed via GPO too.

Comment: FYI, do not copy the full cert (with private key) to other machines or certificate stores.  Keep it in `\My`; preferrably, `CurrentUser\My`.  Only developers responsible for code-signing will need access to the full certificate with private key.  BTW, consider deploying code-signing certs (public key only) into the Trusted Publishers store, as well.  HTH.

Comment: @leeharvey1 Thank you for the informations.... Tomorrow I will check the -NotAfter and -CloneCert parameter. Regarding the cert store I dont really understand if I'm honest. How would be the Best Practise, if my Server with the CA is the Domain Controller and my Clients need the cert for executing the PowerShell Script?

Comment: Using your code above as an example, your first line `New-SelfSignedCertificate` creates the full cert (containing key pair w/ both private and public keys).  When you run your second line `Move-Item`, you are actually copying the full cert (w/ private key) into your Trusted Root store.  Don't do that.  Instead, export the public key only, then use that public key in your GPO deployments into Trusted Root CA stores and Trusted Publishers stores on other systems.  Again, only a developer responsible for code-signing needs the full cert (w/ private key).  HTH.

Comment: Thank you @leeharvey1. I will try out on Friday and share with you my experience. Thank you very much for your help so far, it's a pleasure that I get this answers finally answered....

Comment: Hi @leeharvey1 I hope you had a nice weekend. I tried your method and tried to sign the certificate from the My Folder instead of Root Folder. But with this method i get the same error as stated in this Post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46331902/signing-a-powershell-script-with-self-signed-certificates-and-without-makecert. The Workaround from this users in the post, was to put it in the Root Folder. Do you have a Workaroud for the Status: Unknown Error when I want to sign it?

Comment: **Status: UnknownError** is due to lack of trust.  You'll need to export the public key only from your cert, then import it (public key only) into your Trusted Root CA store and your Trusted Publisher store (or deploy it via GPO). Then, this will work: `$cert = Get-ChildItem -Path 'Cert:\LocalMachine\My' | Where-Object -Property Subject -EQ -Value 'CN=PowerShell Trusted Authority'; Set-AuthenticodeSignature -Certificate $cert -FilePath .\xxx.ps1 -TimestampServer http://timestamp.digicert.com -HashAlgorithm sha256` without the Status: UnknownError.